# Many website doesn't load in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have been facing this problem quite a while. Many website like pinterest, linkedin etc didn't used to load (for chrome `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`). After looking for a while, I found a solution which involves changing the mtu `ifconfig enp7s1 mtu 1496`. It solved most of the problem. But right now, I'm facing problem with authentication, like logging into any website or creating a new account or password recovery. I've faced problem with password recovery of this site too (though for logging in, there weren't any issue).

I've tried different browsers, clearing cache and every other thing but nothing seems to work. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have the same problem in Firefox ? If you disable all extensions in chrome, does the problem persist ?

Comment: Yeap, I've tried both firefox and chrome. I don't have any installed plugins in any of them. But there are some default ones, I've tried disabling them too but the problem still persists. @JonasCz

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664177

The bug has been squashed upstream, and they say that "the updated package should be released soon".
This bug was fixed in the package chromium-browser - 53.0.2785.143-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1145" (source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1641380)